# CSS not working on table populated by ajax response

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a table which is getting populated by the response of ajax call(JSON). But the minimal css like padding, increasing the width of 'td' are not working on that table. I suppose the issue is related to loading of DOM elements. But can anyone share with me what the exact problem is? And how should I go about solving it?